# Fill a web form with data from excel (macro)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I am new to VBA and I am struggling to find a solution for my problem. I have an excel database with UNs and PWs for a number of profiles. I also have an administrator UN and PW and each time I want to access an online editing portal I have to type or copy data in 4 boxes. Since I have to jump between profiles all the time, it wastes a lot of my time. I have started making a macro to do this in one click directly from excel. I have used the send key command for the two boxes that always receive the same text, what I need is to send data from a selected range (1 cell for UN, other for PW) in excel to the form.

**So what I mostly need to translate to a excel VBA is:**

- **copy selected 2 cells**
- sendkey UN
- sendkey {tab}
- sendkey PW
- sendkey {tab}
- **paste first cell in boxX**
- **{tab}**
- **paste second cell in boxY**

Any help or reference is very much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)? Why do you need to use excel?

Comment: I don't need it for personal use. Database is for multiple administrators and is accessed from different computers. As far as I can tell, a macro is the easyest solution. I have gotten to a point, where I can login if the UN and PW in excel are in cells A1 and B1. I need this cells to be "currently selected" cells and not at a fixed position.

Comment: No problem, modify your question to include the code you've written already and we'll be happy to let you know how to adjust it!

Comment: I have solved the problem with help from a friend. The trick is to fist do a simple copy selection to A1:B1 and then the rest of it. I just hide the first row and done.

Comment: Be sure to post your VBA code as an answer and accept it, in case others have this question!

Comment: @tim For future reference, VBA questions are better asked at Stack Overflow.